# Instalar dlib en Python 3.7.3

Tags: python

El caso es el siguiente:

Intento instalar el módulo **dlib** para un proyecto de Python. Necesito lo siguiente; cmake, dlib, face_recognition, numpy y opencv-python. A través de la terminal y usando pip he podido instalar todos los paquetes sin problemas hasta que llegamos a dlib. Para instalar face_recognition es necesario tener dlib (error que el propio pip me señala), pero, a la hora de instalar dlib desde pip (mediante *pip install dlib*) solo obtengo una verborrea de errores de varias lineas (adjunto captura del error abajo).

He probado a instalarlo desde la terminal en Visual Studio y desde la consola de comandos de Windows (con permisos de administrador y sin ellos). Buscando por Google la posible solución, me encuentro con un blog que explica como instalarlo (por desgracia para Python 3.6) entrando en --> *https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/* y ejecutando:

```
python -m pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/ce/f8a3cff33ac03a8219768f0694c5d703c8e037e6aba2e865f9bae22ed63c/dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=794994fa2c54e7776659fddb148363a5556468a6d5d46be8dad311722d54bfcf
```

Lamentablemente, como ya he dicho, esto funciona para Python 3.6 y por tanto me da el siguiente error --> *dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.*

Uso Python 3.7.3 en Windows con Visual Studio y PIP 19.2.1. ¿Hay alguna manera de que pueda instalar dlib en mi maquina?

Un saludo.

PD: Imagen del error 
[image: Error recibido]

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir una captura de los errores que se te muestran? Quizás eso podría ayudar a encontrar una solución

Comment: por lo visto usas windows, tuve un problema similar en la instalacion y era que la version de mi python era 32 bits, la solucion que vi, fue instalar python de 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

Al parecer el problema viene con la instalacion de cmake en windows que no se satisface correctamente. Si estas intentando hacer uso de openCV puedes probar esta guia que te explica paso a paso lo que debes hacer: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-and-dlib-on-windows-python-only/

#### EDIT2

Existen binarios ya compilados (wheels de pip) pero para python3.6. Podrías intentar instalar esa versión de Python si "de momento" no tienes un motivo para usar la última *"per se"*

Comment: Negativo compañero; el error persiste.

Comment: Puedo reproducir tu mismo error en mi equipo, voy a echar un vistazo a ver que puede ser

Comment: Por ahora esa va a ser mi solución. En vista de que no hay binarios listos para la 3.7 tendré que cambiar temporalmente a la 3.6. En caso de que encuentre otra solución ya actualizaré la pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que la solución es esta:

Primero:

```
pip install cmake
```

Segundo:

```
pip install dlib
```

Tercero:

```
pip install face-recognition
```

Yo ahora lo tengo en un entorno con python 3.5.6, lo intentaré con el ultimo.

> **NOTA:** dlib ha tardado un buen rato en instalarse

[image: Librerias instaladas]